# Change PostgreSQL data directory to directory created by PostgresSQL on another machine

Tags: postgresql

I have a database stored on an external hard drive. The database was created using PostgreSQL 11, on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine. The folder it's stored in was the data directory of my PostgreSQL instance on my Ubuntu machine, everything worked fine. I don't have access to this Ubuntu machine anymore, and this will last for a few months, but I have the external drive. I'm working under macOS 14.6 in the meantime. I setup PostgreSQL on my Mac using the Postgres.app. I created a new server, making sure to use version 11. The defaut data directory was of course not the one I want, so I changed its path in postgresql.conf to point to my existing data dir:

```
data_directory = 'path_to_external_HDD_data_directory'
```

Note that this is all I changed in the .conf file (should I change anything else?). When I try to connect to the server via Postgres.app, I get the following error:

> pg_ctl: server did not start in time

And the log is:

```
2019-10-21 22:06:47.628 CEST [72547] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2019-10-21 22:06:47.629 CEST [72547] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2019-10-21 22:06:47.654 CEST [72547] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2019-10-21 22:06:47.742 CEST [72548] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-10-21 22:00:07 CEST
2019-10-21 22:06:58.263 CEST [72548] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2019-10-21 22:06:58.266 CEST [72548] LOG:  redo starts at 4A/B2804E40
2019-10-21 22:06:58.266 CEST [72548] LOG:  invalid record length at 4A/B2804E78: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-21 22:06:58.266 CEST [72548] LOG:  redo done at 4A/B2804E40
2019-10-21 22:06:58.314 CEST [72547] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Postgres.app then tells me that the port is in use. Running `lsof -n -i4TCP:5432`, I see that postgres is listening. I killed it and retried but got the same pg_ctl error. Any idea of what I can do?

Comment: You have probably another instance of PostgreSQL running. Find out which process it is (netstat) and shut it down before you start you PostgreSQL 11 instance.

Comment: I ran `netstat | grep 'postgres'` and it didn't return anything. And I just noticed something weird: despite the errors I described above, the connection is apparently established. Running `psql -U postgres name_of_db` works and lets my interact with the database. I'm completely lost...

Comment: "Postgres.app then tells me that the port is in use."  How did it tell you this?  It is not in the log file you showed.  Presumably it is in use by the database it just now started up (successfully).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server started successfully. You don't use `pg_ctl` to connect to PostgreSQL, but the command line client `psql`.

Anyway, you should stop what you are doing **right now** before any damage is done.

It is **not** supported to use a PostgreSQL data directory created with one architecture (Linux) on a different architecture (MacOS).

If the server starts, it is by coincidence. Connecting *might* work, but it might just as well corrupt your database.

Comment: Ah ok, too bad. Thanks for the info! So basically I can't work for the next few months? I'm gonna get paid for nothing? :)))

Comment: Is there no Linux machine anywhere?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But there's a way around: the database was created from raw text files and I have them, so I'll just create another db from scratch with my mac. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Or a virtual machine?